# Magento - How to add a navigation menu

Tags: magento, navigation

I am new to the magento community framework, and I have successfully configured framework with XAMPP.

I need to add a new navigation menu. Can Someone please help me to do this or suggest me any resources?

Comment: you have to add navigation for category ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below :

1) Create the New Category in Magento Admin panel `Catalog => Manage Category => Add Root Category` under the default category.

2) Create new Product in admin panel `Catalog => Manage Products => Add New Product`

and assign the created products to existing created category to check the front end.

Now Front end will show the created category with prouducts.

Comment: i added category and assigned newly created product to it in admin panel which i have activate through catalog>manage product>product Information Tab - categories - selected catagory. but its not affecting in home page, just displaying blank page! is i done something wrong or need to do something else?

Comment: try this - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar

Comment: i am using magento community edition downloaded from magento site and whatever i am doing in admin panel not effecting to frontend. i really not understanding what mistakes i am doing. kindly guide me.

Comment: I think you have made any mistake in code side or either admin panel.let me the site link, i will check and let you know issues

Comment: for now i'm trying it on localhost. i'll upload it n will send you link.

Answer (score 0):

Create a category in admin section under catalog->manage categories.
Put the name of category as the name of menu item required in navigation.
Remember to set Is Active and Include in Navigation to 'yes'.